# Yii Controller Force HTTPS

Tags: php, yii

I would like to know how to force HTTPS (SSL) at Yii Controller Action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this article http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25407-forcing-https-in-yii/

```
class HttpsFilter extends CFilter {
    protected function preFilter( $filterChain ) {
        if ( !Yii::app()->getRequest()->isSecureConnection ) {
            # Redirect to the secure version of the page.
            $url = 'https://' .
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->serverName .
                Yii::app()->getRequest()->requestUri;
                Yii::app()->request->redirect($url);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And even [this](http://www.jaburo.net/?p=40) for more details.

Comment: I have the problem that after HTTPS all my website stay HTTPS. Do you think is good to create HttpFilter?

Comment: You said you need to force HTTPS.. My solution does. Do you need to force HTTPS only for certain controller action?

Comment: Only for UserController and other controllers should be http. When Im in HTTPS all pages stays https.

Comment: That's other case.. Creating custom URL manager to separate secure/unsecure routes is best solution, try out this excellent article http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/407/url-management-for-websites-with-secure-and-nonsecure-pages/ . Please don't be sad. You just described you problem wrong at the first time.

Comment: My bad Bigdan Burim! Thank you you helped me a lot!

Comment: Not `Bigdan Burim`, use `Bogdan Burim` instead, please)) I am glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to apply https force onto your entire application, which is what I needed, you can put this in your protected/components/Controller.php:

```
  public function beforeAction($action) {
    if( ! Yii::app()->getRequest()->isSecureConnection ) {
      $url = 'https://' . 
        Yii::app()->getRequest()->serverName . 
        Yii::app()->getRequest()->requestUri;
      Yii::app()->request->redirect($url);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This is a cleaner solution than filters if you need site-wide https, because with filters you have to apply an array_merge with the parent controller in all children controllers you create.  If you miss one, no https force for that controller.  The minor drawback to this is that it is called after filters have been called, meaning that more processing has been done than we usually want before redirection.

If your needing it on a controller by controller or an action by action basis, filters are what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
private static $secureRoutes = array('site/login'=>'',);

public function filterAccessControl($filterChain)   {

    if(!Yii::app()->getRequest()->isSecureConnection && array_key_exists($filterChain->controller->route, self::$secureRoutes)){
            $this->redirect($this->createAbsoluteUrl($filterChain->controller->route, array(), 'https'));
        return false;
    }
    else if(Yii::app()->getRequest()->isSecureConnection && !array_key_exists($filterChain->controller->route, self::$secureRoutes)){
            $this->redirect($this->createAbsoluteUrl($filterChain->controller->route, array(), 'http'));
        return false;
    }
}
```